# If everything that is placed within Form1() braces is executed while Form initializing?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I placed try/catch block within "Area1" and I've got a feeling that is not being executed constantly while app running. It was executed only once.
Could someone to shed the light on this.
I'm interested if everything is placed between Form1() braces "Area1", is executed only once while Form initializing.
And where I have to put try/catch block if I have not any event handlers and I need constant processing of try/catch block.

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is executed only once during Form Load

Comment: exception in form creators often doesnt go to plan

Comment: @apomene "during Form load", that's not the Load event, that's the constructor. The event can run more than once

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does executes only once when you instantiate the form saying `Form1 frm = new Form1()` since you have placed it inside form constructor

> I have to put try/catch block...

`try..catch` inside constructor? Umm ... not sure why. Constructor are for member initialization purpose, what kind of operation are you performing there that you need a `try` block. Consider using dependency injection if really such need there. cause, if there any exception occurs while constructing the object then the object become useless for the life of application

Comment: I need to put try/catch block somewhere, where it will be processed constantly and won't cause any fails. I've tried to put try/catch block into Area2, that had caused a fail. So where may I put that?

Comment: I need to poll a bool variable. For that I'm using a timer_tick event handler. However, in addition, based on bool variable state I have to process an exception constantly. At the moment I don't know where I have to put try/catch block. Because putting within Area2 has caused a fail.